# Why does iOS Universal link stopped working in 12.2

Tags: ios, ios12, ios-universal-links

Universal link was working fine till iOS 12.1. It has stopped working in iOS 12.2. I was using XCode 10.1 swift 4, to debug code in 12.2 updated my xcode to 10.2 , swift 4.

I have checked the apple-app-site-association which is fine. Application is downloading it perfectly. Path, activitycontinuation, details looks fine. Associated domains are present in entitlements files. 
This code works/setup fine when running < 12.2.

```
{
    "activitycontinuation": {
        "apps": [
            “teamID.bundleidentifier”
        ]
    },
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": “teamID.bundleidentifier”,
                "paths": [ "/validate", "/redirect", "NOT /*" ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Apple has added some changes related to security, is this the reason of not working.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has asked me to create a bug for them.  They think it’s most likely a bug I am running up against.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back!

Comment: @rambo if u have created a bug for applie, can u share the link to it. We have been facing same issue with 12.2 and 12.3. however it works for lower versions

Comment: I think you can not see bugs created by other people. Apple does not provide that feature. It would be good if you create a bug at. https://bugreport.apple.com. Then they might give attention to the issue.

Comment: hi @rambo, we have same problem. I've just opened the bug with Apple too. Have you received any answer from them? Thx!

Comment: Hi Guys ... Yes. I am in talk with their one of the team member, as of now they don't have any solution to this problem. We should tell apple about this issue by any means .

Comment: Hi @rambo, in our case we have found where the problem is: since the updated iOS version the library we use has a problem, details:

Titanium Kit Extensions
TiApp+Addons.m

At line 129:
[self tryToInvokeSelector:@selector(application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:)
withArguments:[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithObjects:application, userActivity, restorationHandler, nil]];
Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks @JoanmiBardera for replying. I am not using Titanium , I am getting this issue in swift. 

.
.
.

I got the reply from Apple.

`The Universal Links engineers don't currently have additional questions for you, but are actively discussing the issue. Based on the conversations, it still appears this is a bug that the team will need to resolve, but there’s no resolution currently identified, and no timeframe for resolution.`

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: any news @rambo

Comment: We went to WWDC and explained the issue to apple developer. He told me to change the code flow, implement HTML page which will deep link iOS application, that approach is working .. he also told us that apple is making ASWebAuthentication very rich .. so we will not get these issue in iOS 13. For now change the flow in the code, APPLE IS NOT DOING ANYTHING TO FIX THIS ISSUE. Apologies for late reply .

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by replacing teamID with the app prefix in the appID under details of apple-app-site-association file. also keep the apps section empty.

Comment: Same apple-app-site-association works for iOS 12.1 therefore I am narrowing down my doubts to iOS 12.2 changes dune by apple